# LayoutInflater won't inflate WebView

Tags: android, webview

So I'm trying too inflate a WebView, but it won't work, any idea why?

Code:

```
void SuperEttan(){

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    l.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.superettan, null);


    WebView wv = (WebView) customView.findViewById(R.id.superettanContent);
    String content = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://svenskfotboll.se/widget.aspx?scr=table&amp;ftid=35420&amp;b1=%23233446&amp;f1=%23ffffff&amp;b2=%23acbfda&amp;f2=%23000000&amp;b3=%23ffffff&amp;f3=%23000000&amp;b4=%23ececec&amp;bo=%23dfdfdf&amp;s=1'></script>";

    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.google.se", content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "http://www.google.se");
    l.addView(customView);

}
```

All answers are very appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Is there an error? Of so, post logcat. Also, what is `SuperEttan()` part of?

Comment: There are no errors, the view just blank. Superettan is part of an ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really complete but from what I can see, you're trying to add a `WebView` to a linear layour which is in already inflated view.

You should not be inflating any more views. Rather than that, define all properties of your `WebView` programmatically and add it in the code. Alternatively, add it to your main layout file and show/hide as needed.